# Changing a variable from another class

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a primary class (primary as in it has most of the code, the run method, etc) that is running and a Thread running in a different class, can the Thread change a [public static] boolean that resides in the primary class and the primary class reacts accordingly?

Please specify if I'm being unclear!

Comment: The thread likely has access to the variable, so yes, it could be changed by that thread.  But only if you explicitly reassign the variable.

Comment: A class can't _react_ to anything.  Only threads can make things happen.  A class is just a collection of methods and other information that describe a particular type of object, plus maybe some static fields.  (Note: Every program has at least one thread.  Even if it does not create any new threads, there is always the "main" thread.)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to static public members from an other class from a Thread. But, think about concurrent acces. So you need to protect the access to this member using the Java keyword `synchronized`.

The best way to do that is:

```
private static String thing = "dskfjksf";

public static void setThing(String newValue) {
    synchronized(thing) {
        thing = newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not just `static` members.  Threads, by definition, all run in the same address space.  Every thread can _potentially_ access any object in the JVM.  All it needs is a reference...

Comment: @jameslarge I did not say that there is only the static members which can be accessed, but the question is about a public static member: "can the Thread change a [public static] boolean"

Comment: True enough.  I just thought, somebody's going to see "you can do X", and think it means you can _only_ do X.